# Configure JMS endpoint in WebLogic

Tags: java, soap, jms, weblogic, mq

I have an existing application in WebSphere that connects to a remote WebSphere MQ Queue using SOAP over JMS. The endpoint defined in the application running on WebSphere is as follow:

```
jms:/queue?destination=WS.SOAP.SERVER.REQ@MQ_DEV&connectionFactory=(connectQueueManager(MQ_DEV)binding(client)clientConnection(10.10.10.10%25281417%2529)clientChannel(TESTNOSEC))&initialContextFactory=com.ibm.mq.jms.Nojndi&targetService=soap.webclient.Request.java&replyDestination=WS.SOAP.SERVER.RESP
```

I am migrating the application from WebSphere to WebLogic 12.1.2. Without making any changes I get the following error when calling the interface:

```
An exception occurred: javax.xml.rpc.ServiceException: java.net.MalformedURLException: unknown protocol: jms
javax.xml.rpc.ServiceException: java.net.MalformedURLException: unknown protocol: jms
```

Looking at the WebLogic documentation, I assume I'm supposed to create a `JMS Bridge` between WebLogic and WebSphereMQ. What is not clear from the documentation is how do I convert the above endpoint into the relevant values for WebLogic Bridge Destination, Connection Factory and Queue JNDI?

Once the Bridge is configured, I assume I  need to change the connection details.

The current code is as follow:

```
    RequestServiceLocator requestServiceLocator = new RequestServiceLocator();
    requestServiceLocator.setSoapwebclientRequest_WmqEndpointAddress(serviceEndpoint);
    Request port = requestServiceLocator.getSoapEsocketwebclientRequest_Wmq();
```

Does this need to be completely rewritten into something using Message Driven Beans (MDB)?

Comment: This is an excellent code example of a bridge between weblogic and rabbit MQ, which should be similar: https://java.net/projects/weblogic-examples/sources/weblogic-12c-user-examples/show/jeffrey.west/amqp-bridge?rev=178 Note how the weblogic connections are created. Also see:  http://weblogicadminguru.blogspot.com/2013/01/messaging-bridge-in-weblogic.html